DDNS domain name registration
I need some help understanding what is meant here:

Second part is to point "nas.example.com" to the selected DDNS domain
name. Open the domain registration page at Hover and add a registry
record "nas" (or "nas.example.com") with record type "CNAME" and
target host "SOMEPERSONALPREFIX.myDS.me". It takes a little while to
propagate the new record, so be patient when trying to access your NAS
using "nas.example.com".

I would comment directly to the question but I don't have enough points.
From this question:

How to create and connect subdomain to Synology


Can you explain further what part of this you don't understand? It appears this answer is regarding a specific DNS registrar, Hover, but the principles are pretty common and basic.
